# Create new server in SQL Server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our office we have two servers (development and Test). I need to create a new server for practice purpose. How can do it?

Comment: Do you want to create new database for practice or separate database server for practice??

Comment: Install SQL Server on this machine a third time - pick an instance name that's not already in use

Comment: i need a separate database server. So re-installation is the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a physical machine; Install a new server and install sql.
If it's a virtual machine you can always clone the image and change the settings.

You also have the option to copy the database and run it on the development or test server as a separate database with a different name. If you just want to test some stuff and dont want to risk causing problems for the other developers this is probably the best option.

Another option is to install the sql server on your pc, copy the db and test stuff.

I suspect the last option is the one you want?

Comment: It is a virtual machine. but do i clone the image and change the settings?

Comment: Yes. You can refer to http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1027865 if you use vCenter, the process should be similar for other enviroments. Just dont forget to change ip, computername etc etc.